# Error: Longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length covid-19 data R

Tags: r

I am trying to filter a large dataframe that has country based information on COVID-19. When filtering the first 4 countries it comes back without errors:

```
df<-response[response$CountryName==c("Argentina","Australia", "Canada", "China"),]
```

But adding another one to the list (the 5th country) I get an error:

Warning message:

```
In response$CountryName == c("Argentina", "Australia", "Canada",  :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I can't figure out why I'm getting this error. The dataframe has all countries' data, but when I add another entry (the 5th, 6th, ...) I get this error.

Thanks

Comment: `==` compares first to first, second to second, etc. You want `%in%` here. `response$CountryName %in% c("Argentina", "Australia", ...)`

Comment: Also I think you have a typo in your spelling of Argentina.

Comment: Great, got it. Thanks! Good find as well.